# SSRS created 2 conditional counts and get same result for both

Tags: count, conditional-statements, ssrs-2012

I have a very simple SSRS report - a census of employees with health insurance.  I need a count of how many have single policies and how many have family policies.  I created a conditional COUNT statement using the two parameters.  However, they both produce the TOTAL number of policies instead of only the parameter they are supposed to be filtering on.

Expressions I used:
=COUNT(IIF(Fields!Deduction.Value = "Single", Fields!Deduction.Value,0))
=Count(IIF(Fields!Deduction.Value = "Family", Fields!Deduction.Value,0))

I have 79 rows.  54 rows say "Single" and 25 rows say "Family".  The output shows 79 for BOTH groups.

The "Single" and "Family" designation is based on a case statement that converts multiple kinds of policies into the 2 basic values of Single and Family.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a **COUNT** of results.

**0** is a result that counts as **1** the same as any other number.

Use **NOTHING** instead of 0. **COUNT**s do not include NULL (NOTHING) values.

```
=COUNT(IIF(Fields!Deduction.Value = "Single", Fields!Deduction.Value, NOTHING))
```

The other way would be to assign a 1 for a match, 0 for non-match and then **SUM** the results.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Deduction.Value = "Single", 1, 0))
```

Comment: PERFECT!  Thank you so much!  I am VERY new to SSRS reports creation and this was very helpful!